# Query to Return Records When Two or More Values< 2 at Same Time in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (extract below) of test results. I would like to be able to run a query to return the Time, Param, Test and Value where there are two or more values less than 2 at the same time in the same Param.

Extract:

| Time | Param | Test | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 1 | 2.74 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 2 | 3.65 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 3 | 2.26 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 4 | 29 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 5 | 50 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 6 | 80 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 7 | 70 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 8 | 120 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc1 | 9 | 180 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 1 | 2.74 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 2 | 3.65 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 3 | 2.26 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 4 | 29 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 5 | 50 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 6 | 80 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 7 | 70 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 8 | 120 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc1 | 9 | 180 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 1 | 1.955 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 2 | 3.65 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 3 | 1.22 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 4 | 29 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 5 | 50 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 6 | 80 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 7 | 70 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 8 | 120 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 9 | 180 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 1 | 2.74 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 2 | 3.65 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 3 | 2.26 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 4 | 29 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 5 | 50 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 6 | 80 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 7 | 70 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 8 | 120 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc1 | 9 | 180 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 1 | 33 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 2 | 4 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 3 | 2.2 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 4 | 8.3 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 5 | 11.3 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 6 | 11 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 7 | 18 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 8 | 88 |
| 14:38:23.863 | cc2 | 9 | 12 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 1 | 33 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 2 | 4 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 3 | 2.2 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 4 | 8.3 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 5 | 11.3 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 6 | 11 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 7 | 18 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 8 | 88 |
| 14:38:23.881 | cc2 | 9 | 12 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 1 | 33 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 2 | 4 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 3 | 2.2 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 4 | 8.3 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 5 | 11.3 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 6 | 11 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 7 | 18 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 8 | 88 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc2 | 9 | 12 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 1 | 33 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 2 | 4 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 3 | 2.2 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 4 | 8.3 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 5 | 11.3 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 6 | 11 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 7 | 18 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 8 | 88 |
| 14:38:23.940 | cc2 | 9 | 12 |

For this extract the desired result would be:

| Time | Param | Test | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 1 | 1.955 |
| 14:38:23.910 | cc1 | 3 | 1.22 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.value < 2.0 and
      exists (select 1
              from t as t2
              where t2.time = t.time and t2.param = t.param and
                    t2.value < 2.0 and t2.test <> t.test
             );
```

Comment: This is great Gordon, much appreciated.